# Make multiple HashSets using a loop Java

Tags: java, for-loop, hashset

I'm trying to write code that will create multiple HashSets using a for loop. I'm trying to store occurrences of unique words based on their length.  For example, a word of length 4 would go in HashSet A, while a word of length 20 would go in HashSet B.  Instead of creating 16 HashSets manually, is there a way for me to use a for loop `(int i=4; i<21; i++)`? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than having 16 different `HashSet`'s, you can have a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>`.

So, while adding, you can just test whether a `key` is already there or not. If a key is there, just add the word to the `Set` for that key, else add a new entry.

So, here're the steps you need to follow: -

- Get the length of the word. Say `length`.
- Test if `Map` contains key `length` - [`Map#containsKey(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)
- If `length` key is there, get the `Set` for that key - [`Map#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29). And add the `word` to that `Set`.
- If `length` key is not there, create a new `HashSet`, add the current word in it. And add a new entry in your `Map` with the current length as key - [`Map#put(K, V)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one last question, how do I add a word to the set?

Comment: @EricaFischer-Colbrie.. Use `Set#add(Object)` method

Answer (score 2):

You can make them in a loop and put them into a list or an array...

```
List<HashSet<String>> sets = new ArrayList<HashSet<String>>()

for (int x=0;x<16;x++) {
  sets.add(new HashSet<String>());
}
```

Comment: why do you increment `x` twice?

Answer (score 2):

```
HashSet<String>[] sets= HashSet<String>[21];
for(int i=4; i<21; i++)
  sets[i]= new HashSet<String>();
```

Later when you want to add words:

```
for(String word: words){
  sets[word.length()].add(word);
}
```

P.s. I do not use the array indexes 0..3 but the code looks nicer this way and it is really only very little wast of memory.